# developing javascript for Safari -- prevent ball of death

Tags: javascript, debugging, safari, crash

I find myself writing a lot of code like the following, and I still get a lot of ball of death crashes.  It makes the whole code-writing process a lot more painful that it feels like it should be.  Any better approaches out there?

```
function drawArrowsInDocument (document, boxes, context) {
    console.log ("drawArrowsInDocument");
    var body = document.body;
    if (!body) {
        console.log ("no body!");
        return;
    }
    var rectangles = rectanglesWithBoxes(boxes);
    if (!rectangles) {
        console.log ("no rectangles!");
        return;
    }
    var descendants = body.childNodes;
    if (!descendants) {
        console.log ("no descendants");
        return;
    }
    var length = descendants.length;
    if (length>10000) {
        console.log ("too many descendants");
        return;
    }
    // now I know my variables actually exist, and I can do something with them.
```

Here is what I see when it crashes.  The only thing I can do at that point is to restart Safari, and put in some more if statements to find the problem.

[image: crash]

Comment: I find Chrome less unstable and almost the exact same engine. You can also use `throw` to stop a script at any time. Ball of death is most common in infinite loops, so reconsider those while loops.

Answer (score 0):

Use [assertions](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/) instead of console.log. There is the built-in `console.assert`:

```
console.assert(Number("a"),"Not a Number",Number("a"))
```

[Unit testing frameworks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg655487.aspx) can help separate your tests from your code, to avoid the need to remove console statements before deployment.

**References**

- [Safari Web Inspector Guide: Console API](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Console/Console.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH6-SW3)